# Cannot use new installed theme

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, 404-page, 404

I have uploaded my theme using SFTP, and extracted the .tar.gz into the magento install directory (/var/www/html/).

The Magento 1.9 docs state to run the following commands upon install within the Magento install directory:

> find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
>
> find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
>
> find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
>
> find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
>
> find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
>
> find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
>
> chmod 700 includes
>
> chmod 600 includes/config.php

But I still recieve a 404 error when trying to use the theme. Even if I set all files and directories to 775 permissions, and chown with www-data . I still get a 404 error when trying to use the "Theme Install" within the admin panel.

When I try and visit the frontend of my site, there are a few elements loaded from the theme, but 99% of the theme is missing (Home slider, navigation bar, stock logo).

I have uploaded everything correctly to my site, but still get a 404 error when trying to use anything. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that all the files were uploaded?

Comment: @tjons Yeah, I used Filezilla with no failed transfers. I'm going to assume it's a permissions issue but I don't understand how (unless I'm missing something)

Answer (score 1):

May be theme you have uploaded has different ownership

you can check ownership by firing this command in your magento root

`ls -al`

for magento instance change your owner by following

1) login your ssh access

2) fire this command `cd your magento path`

3) change owner ship to www-data  `chown -R www-data:www-data .`
Note : `.` for current directorie and `-R` for recursive

Comment: Hello, I have already ensured my whole /var/www/html/ is owned by www-data, thanks for your reply!

Comment: @PublicDisplayName is your theme working with default theme

Comment: Yes my theme is set as default